# Nested Filtering json file with jq statement

Tags: bash, awk, jq

I have a json file with the following structure of each object inside

```
{
  "id": 2400321267,
  "data": {
    "q": "quinoa black bean and shrimp r",
    "r": "quinoa black bean and shrimps r",
    "s": "3"
  },
  "job_id": 1413792,
  "results": {
    "judgments": [
      {
        "id": 5022700047,
        "unit_state": "good",
        "data": {
          "rewrite_quality": "1"
        },

      }
    ],

  }
},

{
  "id": 2400321267,
  "data": {
    "q": "quinoa black bean and shrimp r",
    "r": "quinoa black bean and shrimps r",
    "s": "3"
  },
  "job_id": 1413792,
  "results": {
    "judgments": [
      {
        "id": 5022700047,
        "unit_state": "good",
        "data": {
          "rewrite_quality": "2"
        },

      }
    ],

  }
}
```

and I was trying to use the command `jq '.[] | select(any(.Tags[]; .rewrite_quality == "1"))' | less` to try to see if the output is correct but I don't see any output.

I want the output to have only entries with rewrite_quality == '1', in this case only the first entry.

Comment: What does the desired output look like?

Comment: I want the entries that have the rewrite_quality value == 1.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON as given. `jq . <<<"$s"` emits `parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 18, column 7`. Please ensure that we can test your input against your stated code without needing any changes whatsoever.

Comment: (Also, the `.Tags` in your jq doesn't seem to make any sense with the input data, which has no `Tags` keys anywhere; please make sure the code and data line up with each other).

Comment: ...that said, as a high-level guess that can't be tested until we're given correct input, it looks like you want something more like `any(.results.judgments[].data.rewrite_quality == "1")`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Reading between the lines, it would appear that the following filter should achieve the stated goals:

```
.[]
| select( .results | any(.judgments[]; .data.rewrite_quality == "1"))
```

#### "Tags"

If the intent in using ".Tags" was to indicate that it does not matter what path leads to `.rewrite_quality`, then the filter to use would be:

```
.[]
| select( any(.. | objects | .rewrite_quality == "1"))
```

#### Alternative to using `less`

If you want a brief indication of whether there are any matches, you could use this filter, which has the added value of revealing how many objects satisfy the criterion:

```
map(select(any(.. | objects | .rewrite_quality == "1"))) | length
```